# PHP Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php

I have a `mysqli_query` like this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT `id` as `id`, `age` as `age` FROM `register` WHERE `age` !="") as a INNER JOIN (SELECT `one` as `f1` FROM `friends` WHERE `two`='".$my_id."' UNION SELECT `two` as `f2` FROM `friends` WHERE `one` = '".$my_id."') as b ON a.id=b.f1
```

When I run this in my `SQL` it gives no error and shows a successful query but if I run it in my browser I get this error

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\wamp\www\functions.php on line 585

Please anyone with an idea on how I can fix this?

This is my entire code

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

    mysqli_select_db($con, 'qings');

    $my_id = '1';
    // the line below is my line 585
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT `id` as `id`, `age` as `age` FROM `register` WHERE `age` !="") as a INNER JOIN (SELECT `one` as `f1` FROM `friends` WHERE `two`='".$my_id."' UNION SELECT `two` as `f2` FROM `friends` WHERE `one` = '".$my_id."') as b ON a.id=b.f1");

?>
```

Comment: please provide some dode

Comment: Show the relevant PHP code, the error is not in the SQL query yet

Comment: You need to post the PHP code that generates the error. It's in `C:\wamp\www\functions.php` on line 585, as the error message shows.

Comment: `!= ""` => `IS NULL`

Comment: The line 585 is the query itself which is in the question. I have shown my full code and you can see it yourself

Comment: @Chay22 ... Thanks so much, I removed it and the error is gone :-)

Comment: Your age column is string or number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **WHERE 'age' !=""** to **WHERE 'age' !=''**

**Use**

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT a.* FROM (SELECT `id` as `id`, `age` as `age` FROM `register` WHERE `age` !='') as a INNER JOIN (SELECT `one` as `f1` FROM `friends` WHERE `two`='".$my_id."' UNION SELECT `two` as `f2` FROM `friends` WHERE `one` = '".$my_id."') as b ON a.id=b.f1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just escape double quotes here

```
WHERE `age` != \"\"
```